# How to enable hostname resolution (dns) for lxd containers from the lxd host?

Tags: dns, lxd

How to enable lxd hostname resolution from the lxd host?

After creating the below container:

```
>>> lxc launch ubuntu: container
Creating container
Starting container

>>> lxc list
+-----------------+---------+----------------------+------+------------+-----------+
| container       | RUNNING | 10.240.38.157 (eth0) |      | PERSISTENT | 0         |
+-----------------+---------+----------------------+------+------------+-----------+
```

It can be reached using the IP address but not using the hostname:

```
>>> ping 10.240.38.157 -c 3
PING 10.240.38.157 (10.240.38.157) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.240.38.157: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.082 ms
64 bytes from 10.240.38.157: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.053 ms
64 bytes from 10.240.38.157: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.041 ms

--- 10.240.38.157 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2044ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.041/0.058/0.082/0.019 ms

>>> ping container
ping: unknown host container
```

How to enable the lxd containers to be reached by hostname from the lxd host?

Comment: The solution is now documented at https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/docs/master/howto/network_bridge_resolved/#network-bridge-resolved-configure and in addition there is a method to make the change persistent at https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/docs/master/howto/network_bridge_resolved/#make-the-resolved-configuration-persistent

Answer (score 2):

LXD sets up for you a DHCP & DNS server (`dnsmasq`) that only listens on the `lxdbr0` interface. That's the DHCP server that lets containers have hostnames like `c1.lxd`, `mycontainer.lxd` and so on.
And it works only within the containers, because the containers are autoconfigured with that LXD's DNS server.

If you want the host to understand those `c1.lxd`, `mycontainer.lxd` hostnames, you need to configure your host's DNS client service to also consult LXD's DNS server.

Comment: How can I access this DNS server?

Answer (score 2):

This is an easy way to temporarily add the LXD DNS server to your host machine.

First, add the DNS server of `lxdbr0`.

```
sudo resolvectl dns lxdbr0 $(ip -f inet addr show lxdbr0 | sed -En -e 's/.*inet ([0-9.]+).*/\1/p')
```

Second, make sure all requests to `*.lxd` are sent to that DNS server.

```
sudo resolvectl domain lxdbr0 lxd
```

After this, any requests to `containername.lxd` will be resolved to the container IP address. Make sure to **add `.lxd` to the hostname**.

*Note that this config will be forgotten after a reboot.*